# Why does my storage page say I have 34 GB of Audio files when there are only 2 audio files stored, totaling 2.1 MB?

Tags: internal-storage, storage, insufficient-memory

I've been trying to free up space on my Pixel 2XL, and the Storage menu in Settings says I have 34 GB of audio files stored, but when I go in to the files to try to erase things, I only have two audio files taking up a total of ~2.1 MB. I don't even know where to find what else might be taking up the space, there's nothing else there... Any ideas?

**Storage Menu:**

[image]

**After pressing `Audio`**

[image]

**After pressing `Unknown`**

[image]

**After pressing `VoiceRecorder`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apps may not store files with music file extensions, this is why they cannot be seen as audio files. You should try clearing app data of Apple music or something similar or check in its directory to see what you want to keep. Sometimes android also recognizes file extensions wrong and interprets them as audio files, such as incomplete downloads. You may use apps such as Files Go from Google to optimize your device storage space.